# dependency problem while downloading the google play dwonloader

Tags: apt

I am trying to download and install the google play downloader for ubuntu. I have downloaded the *google play downloader* from [here](http://codingteam.net/project/googleplaydownloader/download). I tried installing it by using `sudo dpkg -i googleplaydownloader_1.7-1_all.deb` from the from my *Downloads* folder. But I just got the following dependency errors.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of googleplaydownloader:
googleplaydownloader depends on python-configparser; however:
Package python-configparser is not installed.
googleplaydownloader depends on python-ndg-httpsclient; however:
Package python-ndg-httpsclient is not installed.
googleplaydownloader depends on python-protobuf (>= 2.4); however:
Package python-protobuf is not installed.
googleplaydownloader depends on python-pyasn1; however:
Package python-pyasn1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package googleplaydownloader (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
googleplaydownloader
```

I tried using `sudo apt-get -f install`. After using it, I attempted `sudo dkpg -i googleplaydownloader_1.7-1_all.deb` once more. Yet, I got some errors as in the following.

```
Selecting previously unselected package googleplaydownloader.
(Reading database ... 294372 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack googleplaydownloader_1.7-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking googleplaydownloader (1.7-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of googleplaydownloader:
googleplaydownloader depends on python-ndg-httpsclient; however:
Package python-ndg-httpsclient is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package googleplaydownloader (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
googleplaydownloader
```

Help me overcome these errors and make a successful install of the google play downloader.

---

**Update 1:**

I have downloaded **python-ndg-httpclient** from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/python-ndg-httpsclient/download). I tried installing it with this command: `sudo dpkg -i python-ndg-httpsclient_0.3.2-1_all.deb`. This time I have encountered with another set of dependency problem. And I wonder how long it will go! The following are the errors.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-ndg-httpsclient:
python-ndg-httpsclient depends on python-support (>= 0.90.0); however:
Package python-support is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-ndg-httpsclient (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
python-ndg-httpsclient
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom Up!**

1. **python-ndg-httpsclient depends on python-support**

   - download it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/all/python-support/download
   - install it: `sudo dpkg -i python-support.deb`
2. **googleplaydownloader depends on python-ndg-httpsclient**

   - download it : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-ndg-httpsclient
   - install it : `sudo dpkg -i python-ndg-httpsclient.deb`
3. **googleplaydownloader finally**

   - you have [download](http://codingteam.net/project/googleplaydownloader/download)ed it already
   - install it now: `sudo dpkg -i googleplaydownloader_1.7-1_all.deb`

Thats It and Thumbs Up :)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Ramvignesh all`.deb` files can be installed through software centre also

Comment: @MuditKapil I'd say terminal installation is more powerful and better.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-configparser python-protobuf python-pyasn1
```

Then install python-ndg-httpsclient which you have downloaded and then googleplaydownloader_1.7-1_all.deb using `sudo dpkg -i x.deb` where x=package name

Comment: `Unable to locate package python-ndg-httpsclient` with your command

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: it works , i just installed

Comment: I've installed from another answer